# How to show 2 cities where i dont get 'an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected'

Tags: sql, boolean

```
SELECT   CoachFirst AS 'First Name', CoachLast AS 'Last Name', CoachCity AS 'City', TeamName AS 'Team'
FROM     tblCoaches A,
         tblTeams B
WHERE    A.CoachID = B.TeamCoach
AND      CoachCity = 'Bowmanville' AND 'Whitby';
```

Every time I execute the code I get the error

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you intend `IN`:

```
SELECT c.CoachFirst AS FirstName, c.CoachLast AS LastName, c.CoachCity AS City,
       t.TeamName AS Team
FROM tblCoaches c JOIN
     tblTeams t
     ON c.CoachID = t.TeamCoach 
WHERE t.CoachCity IN ('Bowmanville', 'Whitby');
```

Notice the other changes that I made:

- Use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Use table aliases that are meaningful, not arbitrary.
- Qualify all column references so you know where they come from.
- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  In fact, just use alias that do not require escape characters.

Comment: It only my first time using mysql

Comment: @JoshuaDelosSantos . . . This is why I share advice on writing clean, maintainable queries.